# Do I need to create object for subclass elements of a main class in c# unity3d?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am sorry if this question is being asked because i missed something incredibly basic.

I have a classes:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class ResponseObject
    {
        public string id;
        public List<PlayerDetails> player_details ;
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class PlayerDetails
    {
        public int name;
        public int image ;
    }
```

And in other script have below code(

```
private ResponseObject resObject = new ResponseObject();
resObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseObject>(m_apiCallResponse);
```

Now when I try to access variables inside PlayerDetials class as below I am getting an

```
Debug.Log(resObject.player_details[0].name);
```

> Error : `Object reference not set an instance of an object` at the Debug line

And I have data at 0th index of the List which I get from making API call, still I am getting the above error.

But above code works if I declare object as

```
private ResponseObject resObject = new ResponseObject();
resObject .player_details = new List<PlayerDetails>(); 
resObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseObject>(m_apiCallResponse);
```

Am I missing something, Do I need to compulsory declare in above manner?

And do I need to place `[Serializable]` on every class that I declare to make `JsonUtility` work, because its not working if I miss Serializable for every class?

Comment: where you fill the list player_details insde the instance of the responseObject? if null you got error

Comment: I am using `resObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseObject>(m_apiCallResponse);` this to fill data which I gets as a jsonString from API call

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I try to access variables inside PlayerDetials class as below
>   I am getting a Null Exception...

That's because the `resObject` variable is `null` or `player_details` is `null`. You have to check if `resObject` is null then check if the Length of `player_details` is `> 0` before accessing it. Since this is a `List`, you have to use `player_details.Count` to perform this check.

These variables can be null when `JsonUtility.FromJson` fail to de-serialize the json because your json does not match the class or when the json does not even match the classes in your question. It can also be `null` when you are missing `[Serializable]`.

You can find out if your json matches your classes by posing it [here](http://json2csharp.com/). Please, do this before commenting under this answer.

> Am I missing something, Do I need to compulsory declare in above
>   manner?

**No**. You don't need to do it the way you are doing it now. Since you are converting string/json to object, there is absolutely **no need** to initialize the variable before calling `JsonUtility.FromJson`.

This is fine:

```
private ResponseObject resObject;

void yourFunction()
{
    resObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseObject>(m_apiCallResponse);
}
```

Or

```
void yourFunction()
{
    ResponseObject resObject  = JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseObject>(m_apiCallResponse);
}
```

Now, if you are using `JsonUtility.ToJson`, the variable you pass to this function *must be initialized* since you are converting that variable object into string/json.

> And do I need to place [Serializable] on every class that I declare to
>   make JsonUtility work

**Yes**. You need that in order to serialize/deserialize each class with `JsonUtility`.